# Error when declaring QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a public function:

```
void determineAction(QStringList tempL); // in header file

void CompArch::determineAction(QStringList tempL)
{


}

//in cpp file
```

I get the error:

```
CompArch.cpp:127:6: error: ‘tempL’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:77:7: error: forward declaration of ‘struct QStringList’
```

any ideas why this might be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add `#include <QStringList>` to the top of your .cpp file. Incomplete type means that your class (QStringList) has already been named before, using [foward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), but the content of it has not been declared.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete type means that the compiler has seen QStringList as class, but did not see the body of the QStringList class header. It looks like you must include a header that does contain the class header body for QStringList.